# PostgreSQL: update field with select statement on the same table

Tags: postgresql, select, random

I need to update a field in a table on a sample randomly selected.
If I run this query it returns correctly the selected 57 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE item1 = 'XX' AND item2 = 'JJJ' ORDER BY random() LIMIT (57)
```

What I want to do now is to apply that SELCT statement to UPDATE the item1 with 'YY', but only for the 57 randomly selected rows.
I try this:

```
UPDATE table
SET item1 = 'YY'
WHERE id_item = (SELECT id_item FROM table WHERE item1 = 'XX' AND item2 = 'JJJ' 
ORDER BY random() LIMIT (57))
```

but it returns the error: "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression".

How can I update a table for a random number of rows?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the "=" operator to be IN instead.

```
UPDATE table
SET item1 = 'YY'
WHERE id_item IN (SELECT id_item 
                  FROM table WHERE item1 = 'XX' AND item2 = 'JJJ' 
                  ORDER BY random() LIMIT (57))
```

Comment: @Adam: And that's with no coffee on a Monday morning! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Chage = to "in".

You need to change it to this:

```
UPDATE table SET item1 = 'YY' WHERE id_item in (SELECT id_item FROM table WHERE item1 = 'XX' AND item2 = 'JJJ' ORDER BY random() LIMIT (57))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use IN operator instead of = for WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE table
SET item1 = 'YY'
WHERE id_item IN (SELECT id_item FROM table WHERE item1 = 'XX' AND item2 = 'JJJ' 
ORDER BY random() LIMIT (57))**
```